# Extracting all dates between two dates in SQL without a calendar table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have such a table :

```
CREATE table #tableTest
        (
        ID int,
        SumVisits int,
        Domain nvarchar(255),
        LoadDate int
        )

insert into #tableTest (ID,SumVisits ,Domain,LoadDate) values (1,67,'cnn.com',20180617),(2,58,'cnn.com',20180624),(3,52,'cnn.com',20180701)
select * from #tableTest order by LoadDate
```

and I would like to have such a structure:

```
  | SumVisits | date
1   67       20180617
2   67       20180618
3   67       20180619
4   67       20180620
5   67       20180621
6   67       20180622
7   67       20180623
8   58       20180624
9   58       20180625
10  58       20180626
11  58       20180627
12  58       20180628
13  58       20180629
14  58       20180630
15  52       20180701
...
```

my First Idea is to use recursive CTE:

```
;WITH GeneratedCalendar AS
(
SELECT
        CAST(convert(nvarchar(255),[LoadDate]) as date) as EndDate
       ,lead(cast(convert(nvarchar(255),[LoadDate]) as date) , 1,NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY [domain] order by [LoadDate] desc) as StartDate
      From Table
      UNION ALL
      SELECT

        EndDate
        ,StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, G.StartDate)
      FROM
        GeneratedCalendar AS G
      WHERE
        G.StartDate < EndDate
)
select *  from GeneratedCalendar
```

but actually, with this sql code I can not generate my desired structure. Do you have any idea for me?

Comment: `it doesn't work` - is there any error messages ?

Comment: No, but I can not generate my desired structure

Comment: Can you explain your structure? Why does `20180624` have a value of 58 for the second (nameless) column? Please provide sample data and expected results

Comment: Looking at your table, I see 0 date columns. Where are those dates ? Are you using an integer to represent a date ? Please change the datatype to date

Comment: Unfortunately I can not change the datatype. they are integer values for date. '20180624' has the value 58 becuase between 20180617 and 20180623 the value should be 67 and then from 20180624 I have a new value

Comment: Oh my, you are using `int` for date. Your recursive cte query reference a column `date` that is not in your `#tableTest`

Comment: I am querying another table with the same structure. I would like to generate a sample for you here

Comment: What does 58 represent? The number of presents made by elves that day in Santa's workshop? Where is it coming from? We can't see what you see, so a column of integers will no header is meaningless to us.

Comment: Summaton of vistis for a website. I thouth you can run the sqlcode  and see data  temptable

Comment: So, tounderstand the requirement, you want every date between *x* and *y*, and the value of column *2* is the value of `SUMV` for that date, or if there is no date, the last value? Correct? Where are the values from *x* and *y* coming from? the `MIN` and`MAX` of `LoadDate` from `#tableTest`?

Comment: I renamed the column "SUMV" as "SumVisits" as per OP's comments

Comment: @Larnufor yes exactlly. The values for _X_ and _Y_ are already in the table

Answer (score 3):

I beleive this meets what you need. Storing your column `LoadDate` as a `int` when it's clearly a date means I had to use a lot of conversions. Store your dates as what they are, a `date`.

Rather than using a Recursive CTE, I used a Tally. An rCTE is likely to use RBAR here, which if you have a large dataset is going to be far slower. The Tally isn't RBAR though, so scales far better. The Tally I've used will cater for up to a period of 10,000 days (which is over 27 years), far more than you'll ever need (I could have used 1,000 but that's only a few years, which may not meet requirements).

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE #tableTest (ID int,
                         SUMV int,
                         Domain nvarchar(255),
                         LoadDate int --Why is this a int????
);

INSERT INTO #tableTest (ID,
                        SUMV,
                        Domain,
                        LoadDate)
VALUES (1, 67, 'cnn.com', 20180617),
       (2, 58, 'cnn.com', 20180624),
       (3, 52, 'cnn.com', 20180701);
SELECT *
FROM #tableTest
ORDER BY LoadDate;

GO

WITH N AS
    (SELECT *
     FROM (VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) V (N)),
Tally AS
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS I
     FROM N N1
          CROSS JOIN N N2
          CROSS JOIN N N3
          CROSS JOIN N N4),
DateTally AS
    (SELECT CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(DAY, T.I, TT.MinDate), 112)) AS DateValue
     FROM Tally T
          CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), LoadDate))) AS MinDate,
                             MAX(CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), LoadDate))) AS MaxDate
                      FROM #tableTest) TT
     WHERE DATEADD(DAY, T.I, TT.MinDate) <= TT.MaxDate)
SELECT TT.ID,
       TT.SUMV,
       DT.DateValue
FROM DateTally DT
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                         *
                  FROM #tableTest TT
                  WHERE TT.LoadDate <= DT.DateValue
                  ORDER BY TT.LoadDate DESC) TT;

GO
DROP TABLE #tableTest;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would generate the dates and then bring in the values:

```
with dates as (
      select min(cast(convert(nvarchar(255), [LoadDate]) as date)) as dte,
                max(cast(convert(nvarchar(255), [LoadDate]) as date)) as lastdate,
      from #tableTest t
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte), lastdate
      from dates
      where dte < lastdate
     )
```

Then bring in the rest of the data.  If the numbers are decreasing:

```
select d.dte, min(t.sumvisits) over (order by d.dte)
from dates left join
     #tableTest t
     on dates.dte = cast(convert(nvarchar(255), [LoadDate]) as date);
```

You may not be so lucky as to know that the numbers are increasing or decreasing.  One method is:

```
select d.dte, t.sumvisits
from dates outer apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from #tableTest t
      where dates.dte <= cast(convert(nvarchar(255), [LoadDate]) as date)
      order by t.loaddate desc
     ) t
```